# Indexed family of elements that aren't contained in a common set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As far as I know an indexed family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is formally a function $A:I \to S$ where $S$ is a set with $A_i \in S$ for all $i \in I$. If this is the case, the disjoint union $\coprod_{i}A_i$ exists. However, there are cases when the members of the family aren't members of a common set (or at least I think that this can occur) and I wondered how this is treated in set theory terms. For example consider the real projective space of dimension $n$, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ and the family $(\mathbb{R}P^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$ As far as I can tell, the members of this family are not contained in a common set.

My questions are the following.

$(1)$ How would a family of sets be defined in such a case?

$(2)$ If $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of sets, do the axioms of set theory guarantee the existence of the union $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ or do they only guarantee the existence of the disjoint union $\coprod_{i \in i} A_i$?

[According to the axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), the image of $A$ should be a set and contain all the $A_i$, thus guaranteeing the existence of the union of all the $A_i$ to exist. Hence, both should exist, the union and the disjoint union. At least in the case where the members are contained in some common set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues implicit in your question. How does this look in terms of axiomatic set theory (say ZFC), and informally, when is a set "natural"?

First, axiomatic set theory. The Axiom of Replacement was designed precisely to handle this situation. Roughly speaking, if we have a "recipe" associating a set with every element of a set $I$ (the so-called index set)--symbolically, $i\mapsto A_i$ for all $i\in I$--then there is a set $\{A_i:i\in I\}$.

The set-theorist Kanamori wrote a paper "In Praise of Replacement", where he puts it this way:

> Replacement is proximate whenever one posits $\{t_i|i\in I\}$ according to some specifiable correlation of $t_i$'s to $i$'s in an index set $I$.

I can go into more detail about the technicalities, if you wish, but perhaps this is enough.

Once you have the set $\{A_i:i\in I\}$, then the Union Axiom guarantees the existence of a set $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, even if the $A_i$'s are not disjoint.

Now, about "naturalness". You wrote:

> ...$\mathbb{R}P^n$ and the family $(\mathbb{R}P^n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$ As far as I can tell, the members of this family are not contained in a common set.

According to ZFC, all the $\mathbb{R}P^n$ are indeed contained in a common set. But I gather that this set feels somehow unnatural to you. About this, I'll just draw your attention to an example (p.6) in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*:

> Example 0.5. Since $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is obtained from $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ by attaching an $n$ cell, the infinite union $\mathbb{R}P^\infty=\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}P^n$ becomes a cell complex with one cell in each dimension. We can view $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ as the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^\infty=\bigcup_n \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't know why I have never heard of this axiom, I definitely should have. If I understand this axiom correctly, it says that whenever there is a way to associate to some element $i$ a unique object $A_i$, the class of all the $A_i$ is actually a set, namely the set $\{A_i \ : i \in I\}$. By the axiom of union I get the existence of $\bigcup A_i$ and there is also a family $(A_i)_{i \in I}$ giving the existence of the disjoint union $\coprod A_i$. So actually both of the unions exist.

Comment: I mistakenly thought that the disjoint union is used as a way to construct the union when the members of the family are not part of a common set, which I now realized makes no sense at all. Anyways, using your axiom, we know that $\{\mathbb{R}P^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ exists and thus the union exists as well. This is the common set you speak of, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: To apply Replacement, you need both the association, but also the index set has to be a set. For example, for any set $i$ we have the associated singleton $\{i\}$, but the class of all singletons is not a set, because the index "set" here is the class of all sets. However, $\{\{i\}:i\in I\}$ will be a set for any set $I$.

Comment: Yes, the index set has to be a set. I assumed that implicitly in my comments. Thank you for clarifying. Is the rest of what I said in my comments correct?

Comment: As far as not having heard of Replacement, a historical sidenote. ZF set theory is named after Zermelo and Fraenkel. Zermelo did *not* include Replacement in his initial list of axioms. Fraenkel proposed it, and Zermelo agreed that it was needed. This is one of the two reasons that Fraenkel's name got attached to ZF.

Comment: Yes, your other comments are correct. $\{\mathbb{R}P^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is the common set. Note however that more is going on in Hatcher's construction of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$, although without Replacement you couldn't formally justify the existence of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ as a mathematical object.

Comment: I see. Again thank you for taking the time to answer. I will accept your answer.